# Multi-line PL/SQL command with .NET OracleCommand

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm using System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand to create a table and fill it out with some data. The query I am using runs OK in PS/SQL Developer, however when I'm trying to execute it from within .NET application I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 20:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor
```

Column 20 is exactly where first line ends. As soon as I remove line end characters (\r\n) from the command it all starts working.

I wonder is there some hidden configuration parameter to enable multi-line queries for Oracle?

Here is some code:

```
               var text = @"declare cnt number;
begin

 select count(*) into cnt from all_tables
 where table_name = 'TABLE_A';


if cnt = 1 then
   begin 
      execute immediate 'truncate table TABLE_A';
      execute immediate 'drop table TABLE_A';
   end;
end if;

execute immediate 'create table TABLE_A as 
 (SELECT DISTINCT v.ID, g.ext_id FROM VIEW_A v
 JOIN TABLE_B B ON v.id = B.Id
 WHERE YEAR1 = ''2008'')';

end;");

            var createTempTable = new OracleCommand(text, conn);
            createTempTable.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();

            try
            {
                createTempTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();    
            }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show more of the code?  It is tough to know what you are doing.

Comment: Slightly off-topic -- Why truncate the table before dropping it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to lose just the '\r' characters.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Shouldn't OracleCommand or Connection objects take care for that though?